# combination of two local query results into one global query variable in LinQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some check box in my C# program, which each one are corresponding to one column of the database-driven table. When each one is checked by the user, program should consider a query, corresponding to that column and store the result in a var type variable. Finally, all of that local var type query results, were which generated into if blocks, need to be combined into one result, as GlobalQueryVar, to be presented in a grid data view.
The if statement of a typical check box is just like below:

```
if(IDCheckbox.checked)
    {
        localQuery0 = from MessageID in DB.AVLDATASets
                      select {MessageID, MessageID};
         if(GlobalQueryVar == null)
            *** GlobalQueryVar == localQuery0; // aren't the same type... How to cast
         else
           ****  GlobalQueryVar == GlobalQueryVar.concat(localQuery0); // apparently, doesn't work...
    }
```

At last, all of the local queries should be attached one by one to the global variable, GlobalQueryVar, then, I am going to use .toArray() method for the GlobalQueryVar and sending the result to the gridview.

Now, I have 3 questions to handle this case:
1- What kind of type should I consider for my GlobalQueryVar?!... IEnumerbale or IQueryable or...?!

2- what's the required casting scheme for the line, signed by ***?!

3- How can I concat the stuffs, deservedly, in the line signed by ****?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `GlobalQueryVar`? `localQuery0` contains items anonymous type, so `GlobalQueryVar` should be collection with items same type

Comment: @Grundy: GobalQueryVar is a global variable in the global scope of the  class. The local query results should be concatenated to it.
The problem is that the output of one local query is integer and the other string...
How should I act in this case?!

Comment: can you provide how you define `GlobalQueryVar`?

Comment: @Grundy: This is exactly my first question above... I don't know how to do that...!
I just tested below declarations... but none of them let me initialize the GlobalQueryVar wih the local one...
"IEnumerable GlobalQueryVar" doesn't work... "IQueryable GlobalQueryVar" doesn't work too...
Actually, I don't know what type it should have

Comment: first: you must decide what you want to store in `GlobalQueryVar`

Comment: then add class for items, and in `select` use not anonymous class

Comment: I want to store the result of localQuery in if statement into it...
But I don't know its type... The getType() function just returns "DataQuery" as its type.

Answer (score 1):

For quick fix you problem you can

1) create class for data like

```
public class MessageData{
    public string Message {get;set;}
    public int MessageID {get;set;}
}
```

2) declare you global var like

```
IQueryable<MessageData> GlobalQueryVar;
```

3) change your query like

```
localQuery0 = from msg in DB.AVLDATASets
              select new MessageData{ Message = msg.Message, MessageID = msg.MessageID};
```

after thar next code should work

```
if(GlobalQueryVar == null)
    GlobalQueryVar == localQuery0;
else
    GlobalQueryVar == GlobalQueryVar.concat(localQuery0);
```